# Assigning structure* to unsigned char * error

Tags: c++, linux, sockets, pointers, struct

I am trying to pass the pointer to a structure to unsigned char * which handles the response answer from the server program. The client also has similar structure to be able to interpret the message. I am not able to assign the pointer to the structure to the pointer to the answer. Is unsigned char * not suitable for this ? How is this kind of operation done ?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>

using namespace std;

struct  SERVER_ANSW
{
    unsigned int    payload_len;    //Payload length of the response 
    unsigned char   answ_flag;      //Reply-send flag 
    unsigned char   *ptr_answ;  //Pointer to answer 
};

struct  SERVER_DESC
{
    int     udpport;                //UDP-Port 
    int     server_port;            //TCP/IPPort
    char        server_ipaddr[16];  //IP-Address of server
    char        server_mac[18];     //MAC-Address of server
};

int main()
{
    SERVER_DESC s_desc;         // Server-Descriptor
    SERVER_ANSW s_ans;          // Server-Answer
     
    s_desc.server_port = 10005;
    strcpy(s_desc.server_ipaddr, "127.0.0.1");
    s_desc.udpport = 5000;

    s_ans.payload_len = sizeof(SERVER_DESC); // payload size assignment
    s_ans.ptr_answ = &s_desc; // void pointer also gets the address
    
    /*
    ...
    // Send the description out via tcp socket using a custom func.
    i_result = send(i_socket,(char *)s_desc.ptr_answ,s_desc.payload_len);
    ...
    */
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You need to use a `reinterpret_cast` to alias the type of a pointer

Comment: Perhaps you want to use `void*` instead of `unsigned char*` here.

Comment: @AlanBirtles I tried your suggestion like the following:     

s_ans.ptr_answ = reinterpret_cast<unsigned char*>(&s_desc); // Using reinterpret_cast
cout << "s_ans.ptr_answ: " <<  (s_ans.ptr_answ)->server_ipaddr << endl; // Does not work!

But this does not work. Could you please tell me where I am doing the mistake ?

Comment: @n.m. I also tried your suggestion like the following:     

s_ans.ptr_answ = &s_desc; // Using void *ptr_answ
cout << "s_ans.ptr_answ: " <<  (s_ans.ptr_answ)->server_ipaddr << endl; // Does not work!!! Why ?

Again this does not work. Could you please help here ?

Comment: @soumya - Once you cast the pointer to `char*` or `void*` you just have bytes, and not a struct. So no member access.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to assign an the wrong pointer type.

-"ptr_answ" is defined as "unsigned char*"
-"&s_desc" is a pointer to "SERVER_DESC"

So, this cannot work.

You have 2 options here:

1. You could use a "void *" as data_type for "ptr_answ"   Or
2. You need to cast the pointer to "SERVER_DESC" to an "unsigned char*" (pointer)

This could then look like the below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>

struct  SERVER_ANSW
{
    unsigned int    payload_len{};    //Payload length of the response 
    unsigned char   answ_flag{};      //Reply-send flag 
    unsigned char*  ptr_answ{};       //Pointer to answer 
};

struct  SERVER_DESC
{
    int             udpport{};        //UDP-Port 
    int             server_port{};    //TCP/IPPort
    char            server_ipaddr[16]{};  //IP-Address of server
    char            server_mac[18]{};     //MAC-Address of server
};

int main()
{
    SERVER_DESC s_desc{};         // Server-Descriptor
    SERVER_ANSW s_ans{};          // Server-Answer

    s_desc.server_port = 10005;

#pragma warning(suppress : 4996)
    strcpy(s_desc.server_ipaddr, "127.0.0.1");
    s_desc.udpport = 5000;
    s_ans.payload_len = sizeof(SERVER_DESC); // payload size assignment
    s_ans.ptr_answ = reinterpret_cast<unsigned char*>( &s_desc);                // void pointer also gets the address
}
```

BTW: Your code is pure C. You still use totally unsafe functions like `strcpy`. Please consider to migrate to C++